# How do I get around the happybase "TApplicationException: Internal error processing mutateRows" error?

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm using happybase to connect to my Hbase database. I made a sample table called 'irisSample'. Here's the part of the code that I'm having trouble with-

```
import happybase
from happybase import *
import json

connection = happybase.Connection('<ip-address>', '9090')

table = connection.table('irisSample')

n = 0
x = 1
for u in y:
    data = {'petalWidth':points['petalWidth'][n], 'sepalLength':points['sepalLength'][n], 
          'petalLength':points['petalLength'][n], 'label': u}
    row = 'row' + str(x)
    table.put(row, {'flowers': str(data)})
    n += 1
    x += 1
```

And I get the following.

```
TApplicationException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-94741a8b04dc> in <module>()
      9           'petalLength':points['petalLength'][n], 'label': u}
     10     row = 'row' + str(x)
---> 11     table.put(row, {'flowers': str(data)})
     12     n += 1
     13     x += 1

/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase/table.pyc in put(self, row, data, timestamp, wal)
    437         """
    438         with self.batch(timestamp=timestamp, wal=wal) as batch:
--> 439             batch.put(row, data)
    440 
    441     def delete(self, row, columns=None, timestamp=None, wal=True):

/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase/batch.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
    130             return
    131 
--> 132         self.send()

/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase/batch.pyc in send(self)
     53                      self._table.name, self._mutation_count, len(bms))
     54         if self._timestamp is None:
---> 55             self._table.connection.client.mutateRows(self._table.name, bms, {})
     56         else:
     57             self._table.connection.client.mutateRowsTs(

/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase/hbase/Hbase.pyc in mutateRows(self, tableName, rowBatches, attributes)
   1574     """
   1575     self.send_mutateRows(tableName, rowBatches, attributes)
-> 1576     self.recv_mutateRows()
   1577 
   1578   def send_mutateRows(self, tableName, rowBatches, attributes):

/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase/hbase/Hbase.pyc in recv_mutateRows(self)
   1592       x.read(self._iprot)
   1593       self._iprot.readMessageEnd()
-> 1594       raise x
   1595     result = mutateRows_result()
   1596     result.read(self._iprot)

TApplicationException: Internal error processing mutateRows
```

I've also tried `json.dumps(data)` instead of `str(data)` which threw the same exception.

From what I'm gathering it seems more like a Thrift problem but I could be wrong. I may have to look at starbase instead. I don't know, that's why I'm asking you guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest). It required a REST framework to be running on an unused port. I then connected to that port and was able to see the list of all the tables in Hbase and insert data into the database. The command is `./hbase-daemon.sh start rest -p <unused port number>`. I couldn't find the answer anywhere and no one even commented for a few days so I hope this helps you! Here's the code. I ended up using `starbase`.

```
import starbase
from starbase import Connection

c = Connection(host='<ip-address>', port=8000)
```

8000 is the default port by the way.

```
t = c.table('irisSample')

for flower in range(len(labels)):
    data = {'petalWidth':X[flower][3], 'petalLength':X[flower][2], 
              'sepalLength':X[flower][0], 'sepalWidth':X[flower][1], 'cluster': labels[flower]}
    n += 1
    row = 'row' + str(n)
    t.insert(row, {'flowers': data})
```

Comment: this is not a solution to the original problem at all. using a completely different access method is not the solution, fixing your data structure is.

Comment: It solved the issue. You can't use THRIFT to put data into the table. The table is clustered and you need to be running REST on an unused port on a different machine if you want to put data into the table. This is the solution. I didn't need to change anything except the machine that I put the data into.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your "data" object you are not giving column family along with the column name.

```
data = {'petalWidth':points['petalWidth'[n], 'sepalLength':points['sepalLength'][n], 'petalLength':points['petalLength'][n], 'label': u}
```

You need to have column family before each of the column values. E.g., say your column family is "cf" then instead of 'petalWidth' you want 'cf:petalWidth'.

```
data = {'cf:petalWidth':points['petalWidth'[n], 'cf:sepalLength':points['sepalLength'][n], 'cf:petalLength':points['petalLength'][n], 'cf:label': u}
```

Doing this fixed the mutateRows error for me.

Comment: You can't use THRIFT to put data in to HBase. That was what the issue was.

Comment: I have used it to put data into HBase. So, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When I tried to use THRIFT I couldn't put the data in, but when I used REST I didn't have to change anything about the code, just the port and the IP address where the data goes into hbase. There were no mutation errors. Maybe you can use THRIFT but I found a way around it.